# Xampp extract :error writing to file libmysql.dll

Tags: mysql, xampp

when i installed xampp in win7,always failed. Error message  display as following:

**Xampp extract :error writing to file libmysql.dll**

How can I solve this problem? AnyBody knows it? I will appreciate your answer.

Answer (score 0):

With the limited information you have given it's hard to know for sure but I'm guessing you have an old `libmysql.dll` on your system. Look for it and remove it or rename it to something like `libmysql.dll.backup` and then try to install xampp again. Also, might be worth installing "as administrator" if you're not already doing that.

Comment: thanks for your reply.I have done it as your say,but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

**"error writing to file"**,the mistake is caused by the lack of  system disk's available space.

After I deleted some files,the software installed successfully!